# Android Emulator: Write file to local file system?

Tags: java, android

I am wondering if its possible to get my android application to save a file to a windows file system or is there a simple work around I can adopt?

I am using the android emulator to do tests and I need it to write to the local hard drive so I can do further processing on the file.

I hope this is possible and I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can save a file to the emulator's SD card and then make `adb pull`.

Comment: That is perfect. `adb pull <remote> <local>`.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using conventional SDK the answer is (probably) no. If you look at ~/.android/avd you will see that whatever your emulator is doing is stored into *.img files. Said that you can create some sort of service running on the localhost and connect to that from your app. This will actually better resemble real-life scenario

Based on your reaction to @pixie answer it looks like I misunderstood your question. Indeed you can simply use your Eclipse DDMS perspective to navigate to the file and then "pull" or "push" a file. You can't just do it programmatically from withing your app

Answer (score 2):

As far as I am aware the answer is no, you can save the file to the SD card or to the application's storage and use the File Explorer tool (Window -> Show View -> Other -> File Explorer) in Eclipse to extract that file to your machine or use the `adb pull` method